# Can someone please tell me how to use a debugger in BlueJ(a Java environment)

Tags: java, debugging, bluej

I'm a student, trying to learn Java. In my school, it is compulsory for someone learning Java to use BlueJ, which is somewhat like a bit simplified version of other Java softwares, like Visual Studio or Eclipse, etc. I think y'all know better than me about this btw...

I'm trying to solve many problems on LeetCode, etc. I encounter many errors; most of them, I solve by myself with just some trial and error, but some can't just be processed by my mind. Yesterday, I discovered that there is a debugger in BlueJ as well. I tried to use it somehow, but I don't understand how it works. I also saw many videos on YouTube, but didn't understand everything.

I can see that it shows the static variables, instance variables and local variables, but other than that, it's game over for me.

So can someone just explain how it works ?

Thanks ✌

Comment: Bring up [Google](https://www.google.com/) in your web-browser and enter: **Does BlueJ have a Debugger**. Start from the top of the list and work your way down.